# How can I remove base currency conversion from the table rate shipping method?

Tags: magento, magento2

The shipping price needs to be set without converting base currency from a CSV file. As the base currency, I have set Kuwaiti dinar, and Saudi Riyal as the default display currency. In the current situation, the CSV price value has been multiplied by the base currency. When I remove the global base currency rate conversion, it affects the conversion of product prices.

[image: Currency rate setup]

[image: Currency Setup]